# showing & symbol in browser address bar using PHP

Tags: php, html

i have a PHP page where i use `$_GET["value"];` to retrieve values from the address bar

I want to be able to do

```
url.com/test.php?value1=one&value2=one&two
```

but when i echo the value2 it doesnt show the `&` symbol

Comment: You need to escape it. Otherwise `two` is its own variable. `url.com/test.php?value1=one&value2=one+%26+two`

Comment: using mysql_real_escape_string ? or something else?

Comment: try url_encode for escape it

Comment: Do you need to use ampersand as a delimiter in this case? Why not a pipe, comma, or colon instead?

Answer (score 1):

You need to use `urlencode()` when you are creating the Url, to escape your ampersand `&`. The ampersand should be `%26` in the url.